# Is there a way to use python's LowLevelCallable with interpolation function?

Tags: python, c, scipy

I'm dealing with an integration involving lots of interpolation functions, e.g.

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate

integrate.quad(lambda t: 1/func_a(t)*(func_g2(tp)*func_g1p(t)-func_g1(tp)*func_g2p(t))
               *func_jl(t)/((tau0-t)**2 * klist[84]**2), tp, tau0, limit=100)
```

where *func_a*, *func_g1*, *func_g1p*, *func_g2*, *func_g2p* and *func_jl* are all interpolation functions (done with cubic spline). Unfortunately the code performance is not satisfactory, so I'm thinking of accelerating it with scipy's LowLevelCallable.

From scipy's documents it seems that I should include in the C code just a function body of my integrand with certain function signature pattern, e.g.

```
double f(double * x, void * userdata)
{
// integrand here, e.g.
// return 1/func_a(t)*(func_g2(tp)*func_g1p(t)-func_g1(tp)*func_g2p(t))
//               *func_jl(t)/(pow(tau0-t, 2) * pow(klist[84], 2));
}
```

where *x* is the argument to integrate upon, and *userdata* contains some other parameters. But this means that there's no place for me to initialize my interpolation functions, unless I provide the table in *userdata* and generate the interpolation function every time I call the integrand (the performance won't be good I guess). So I'm wondering if there's any other ways to either enabling me to practically use the scipy.LowLevelCallable approach with interpolating functions, or accelerate the integration in another way.

Thanks!

Comment: `void * userdata` could be a struct with all kinds of data. The first step would be to implement the algorithm which is behind the interpolating functions. Maybe there is already a C implementation, but without knowing what this functions are all about, it is impossible to answer that.

Comment: @max9111 Indeed there are many C libraries that can do the interpolation if I pass the data points in `void * userdata`. But my point is that the function f contains just the integrand, and I don't want to generate an interpolation every time I call the integrand.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to. eg. if the interpolation function is actually a bspline, you can call https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html#scipy.interpolate.splev (you would call the Fortran function, which does the job or some equivivalent C function) to evaluate the function. You just need to pass t,c,k via *userdata which defines the interpolating function. This parameters can be calculated once before the integration.

Comment: @max9111 Oh I see what you mean. Unfortunately they are (at this moment) all cubic spline, but let me see if I could dig more along this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, but you have to rewrite the interpolating function

You mentioned, that you have cubic splines. Without considering special cases this can quite easily be implemented in C-code. The generation of the splines can be done in Python.

**Example for the low-level callable**

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#    define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define API
#endif

#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
intervalls have to be increasing, no checks are performed.
*/

double eval_spline(double xp,size_t k,size_t m,double *c,double *x){
    size_t interv=0;
    
    for (size_t i=1;i<m;i++){
        if (xp>x[i]){interv+=1;}
    }
    
    k=k-1;
    double acc=0;
    
    for (size_t i=0;i<k+1;i++){
        acc+=c[i*m+interv]*pow(xp-x[interv],k-i);
    }
    return acc;
}

struct data{
   double *cs_1_c;
   double *cs_1_x;
   size_t  cs_1_k;
   size_t  cs_1_m;
   double *cs_2_c;
   double *cs_2_x;
   size_t  cs_2_k;
   size_t  cs_2_m;
};

API double Integrand(double t, void *userdata){
    struct data input=*(struct data*)userdata;
    
    return eval_spline(t,input.cs_1_k,input.cs_1_m,input.cs_1_c,input.cs_1_x)
      *pow(eval_spline(t+0.5,input.cs_2_k,input.cs_2_m,input.cs_2_c,input.cs_2_x),2);
}
```

**How to use the low-level callable from Python?**

This can be accomplished using a ctypes-wrapper including some functions to generate the struct which can be passed using the void-pointer.

```
import ctypes
import os
from scipy import integrate, LowLevelCallable
import numpy as np

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("integrand.dll")

def get_integrand():
    lib.Integrand.restype =  ctypes.c_double
    lib.Integrand.argtypes = (ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_void_p)
    return lib.Integrand

dble_p=ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)
class args_struct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('cs_1_c',   dble_p),
                ('cs_1_x',   dble_p),
                ('cs_1_k',   ctypes.c_size_t),
                ('cs_1_m',   ctypes.c_size_t),
                ('cs_2_c',   dble_p),
                ('cs_2_x',   dble_p),
                ('cs_2_k',   ctypes.c_size_t),
                ('cs_2_m',   ctypes.c_size_t)]

def create_struct(cs_1,cs_2):
    #The arrays must be c-contigous, if not make them c-contiguous
    cs_1_c = np.ascontiguousarray(cs_1.c)
    cs_1_x = np.ascontiguousarray(cs_1.x)
    cs_2_c = np.ascontiguousarray(cs_2.c)
    cs_2_x = np.ascontiguousarray(cs_2.x)
    
    args=args_struct(ctypes.cast(cs_1_c.ctypes.data,dble_p),
                     ctypes.cast(cs_1_x.ctypes.data,dble_p),
                     cs_1_c.shape[0],
                     cs_1_c.shape[1],
                     ctypes.cast(cs_2_c.ctypes.data,dble_p),
                     ctypes.cast(cs_2_x.ctypes.data,dble_p),
                     cs_2_c.shape[0],
                     cs_2_c.shape[1],)
    return ctypes.cast(ctypes.pointer(args),ctypes.c_void_p)

def do_integrate_w_arrays(func,args,lolim=0, hilim=1):
    integrand_func=LowLevelCallable(func,user_data=args)
    return integrate.quad(integrand_func, lolim, hilim)
```

### Comparison of the implementations

Now compare the runtime of a pure Python implementation with the C-implementation.

**Pure Python**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import scipy.integrate as integrate

x = np.arange(10)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)**2

cs_1 = CubicSpline(x, y1)
cs_2 = CubicSpline(x, y2)


def Integrand_orig(t):
    return cs_1(t)*cs_2(t+0.5)**2

%timeit res=integrate.quad(Integrand_orig,a=-0.5,b=10.5)
#15.2 ms ± 237 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Using the low-level-callable**

```
import wrapper

func=wrapper.get_integrand()

args=wrapper.create_struct(cs_1,cs_2)
wrapper.do_integrate_w_arrays(func,args,lolim=-0.5, hilim=10.5)
#136 µs ± 445 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```